# How to choose between IList or IEnumerable as method parameter type

Tags: c#, parameters

I am writing a library and I'm trying to determine the best type to use for method parameters to a method. I'm also trying to determine where to draw the line between being too picky and getting the write method definition.

Here is some code

```
public void MethodTakesIList(IList<MyClass> myClassInstances) {
  List<List<byte>> byteLists = GetByteLists(myClassInstances.Count);
  for (int i = 0; i < myClassInstances.Count; i++) {
    ProcessBytesAndMyClassInstance(byteLists[i], myClassInstances[i]);
  }
} 

public void MethodTakesIEnumerable(IEnumerable<MyClass> myClassInstances) {
  List<List<byte>> byteLists = GetByteLists(myClassInstances.Count());
  int i = 0;
  foreach(MyClass instance in myClassInstances) {
    ProcessBytesAndMyClassInstance(byteLists[i], instance);
    i++;
  }
}
```

In [this](https://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2013/07/22/when-to-use-ienumerable-icollection-ilist-and-list/) article it states that I "should always use that type that provides a contract for only the methods you really use." The method that takes an IEnumerable still defines an index which is used in the loop. Since this index would point to a valid entry **if myClassInstances were a list** does that mean I should just use the method that accepts an IList? I would now have the capability to use the indexer of the IList. Or since **there exists a solution that accepts IEnumerable** should I use that one since it supports the greatest number of inputs?

Comment: Don't worry so much about what type you accept but worry more about performance. `List<T>.Count` is always known, while LINQ's `IEnumerable<T> Count` method must enumerate the entire collection

Comment: Your question, being primarily opinion based, is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. That said, the guidance you are reading is reasonable, and in your scenario means you should use `IEnumerable<T>`.  Always accept as input the least-restrictive type that still works with your implementation. Since in your example, you do not have any actual need to index the input collection, `IEnumerable<T>` suffices and should be used in favor of `IList<T>`. The fact that the implementation involves an index somewhere is immaterial. The only thing that matters is how the parameter must be used.

Comment: Does it enumerate (loop over it) it once? Use `IEnumerable`? Otherwise, use `IReadOnlyList`. That is my general rule. Is it always perfect, no (e.g. you could instead just always use `IEnumerable` and then try and cast to `IReadOnlyList` or call `ToList` **inside** the method as needed). But it is a good rule of thumb. I'd recommend never using `IList` since it is not a great interface, since its two main implementations have such different properties (i.e. you can add to a `List` but not an array). _In your case, I would not use `Count` like you are - just add to the `List` as needed._

Comment: @PeterDuniho perhaps it is opinion based but what if there is some widely accepted design principle that I am unaware of when asking this question? If the answers don't reveal that then in the future I might know that this question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Linq's count method will use the `Count` property if the `IEnumerable` passed in is a list (technically any `ICollection<T>`).

Comment: Why are you using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`? If you don't use that there's no reason to use `IList` at all since you don't need to access the list by index.

Comment: _"what if there is some widely accepted design principle"_ -- widely accepted opinions are still opinions. There are other forums, including other Stack Exchange sites, where opinions are the main currency, and where a question like this would be appropriate. But Stack Overflow questions should be able to be answered in objectively, factually-correct ways.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable` is generally a safe bet if you are unsure how people will use the API. There are plenty of cases when a user will not have a `IList` object, especially when using things from Linq, in addition to any other collections other than lists, such as `LinkedList` or `Queue`.

For example if they do `someList.Select((x) => new OtherThing(x, "test"))`, filter with `Where`, etc., then they will end up with an `IEnumerable`. While there is also in `System.Linq` a convenient `myEnumerable.ToList()` it is an extra conversion they would have to do and has some performance impact, maybe worse than the one you hoped to avoid.

Of course, there are times when for performance reasons other types are preferable, especially when dealing with large amounts of small values (e.g. `byte[]`), or making your implementation simpler, for example for random access or modifying the data.

You have to consider the trade offs yourself, although you might take inspiration from the standard classes and other popular libraries for the language. For public libraries you also have to be very careful in considering binary compatibility, for example if you return an `IEnumerable` then you can change your implementation to use a different actual type, if you return a `List` or even `IList` then you are more limited in what is technically possible without breaking compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would take inspiration from how Microsoft implemented LINQ. Many of the operators that could benefit from being able to use a collection type still have `IEnumerable<TSource>` as the source data, but they simply try to cast to `ICollection<TSource>` to get direct access to indexing and other properties.

Take (this slightly modified) `Count`, for example:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        return collection.Count;
    }
    ICollection collection2 = source as ICollection;
    if (collection2 != null)
    {
        return collection2.Count;
    }
    int num = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            num = checked(num + 1);
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

If the input type is castable to a collection then the `Count` operator simply returns the count; otherwise it iterates through the list.

That way you get the best of both types.